# CASE dentro de clausula WHERE - ORACLE

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Buen dia, 
tengo un query en el cual dependiente del tipo de reporte que se quiera hace diferente la busqueda cuando la BANDERA es igual a "A" busca en el campo de FECHA_APLICACION y cuando BANDERA = "B" busca en el campo de FECHA
 trate de usar case en el where pero no se que estare haciendo mal ,  a continuacion parte del query

```
where  (CASE WHEN V_BANDERA='A' THEN 
to_char(pto.FECHA_APLICACION,'yyyyMMdd') between V_FECHA_IN  and 
V_FECHA_FIN
WHEN V_BANDERA='B' THEN to_char(pto.FECHA,'yyyyMM')=V_PERIODO  
END)
```

la descripcion del error al momento de compilar el package

> [Warning] ORA-24344: success with compilation error
>   91/79   PL/SQL: ORA-00905: missing keyword
>   14/1    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
>    (28: 0): Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dado que Oracle maneja un tipo booleano a nivel PL mas no en SQL, puedes hacer la misma lógica pero con un número entero 0/1:

```
WHERE CASE 
         WHEN  V_BANDERA='A' 
           AND to_char(pto.FECHA_APLICACION,'yyyyMMdd') between V_FECHA_IN and V_FECHA_FIN
           THEN 1
         WHEN  V_BANDERA='B'
           AND to_char(pto.FECHA,'yyyyMM')=V_PERIODO  
           THEN 1
         ELSE 0
      END = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero trabajemos como dice la sintaxis del **to_char**

```
where (CASE WHEN V_BANDERA='A' THEN 
to_char(pto.FECHA_APLICACION,'YYYYMMDD') between V_FECHA_IN and 
V_FECHA_FIN
WHEN V_BANDERA='B' THEN to_char(pto.FECHA,'YYYYMM')=V_PERIODO  
END)
```

Segundo podrías trabajar con la sintaxis del **to_date**

```
where (CASE WHEN V_BANDERA='A' THEN 
to_date(pto.FECHA_APLICACION,'YYYY/MM/DD') between V_FECHA_IN and 
V_FECHA_FIN
WHEN V_BANDERA='B' THEN to_date(pto.FECHA,'YYYY/MM')=V_PERIODO  
END)
```

Esto esperando que la funcion **to_date** te funcione como el **to_char**, atendiendo esto para verificar el error que te lanza que podria ser que envias mal los datos en la sintaxis del **to_char**

Saludos